# Adding a Splash Screen to a react-router-dom Reactjs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, splash-screen

I'm trying to add a splashscreen to my ReactJS project and I've managed to make it... somewhat. It does load when component mounts, however, it runs even when I navigate back to the main page. The code is as below:

Home.jsx

```
import styles from "./styles/Home.module.css";
import Layout from "../components/layout/Layout";
import SplashScreen from "../splash-screen";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home(props) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 4000);
  }, []);

  return isLoading ? (
    <SplashScreen />
  ) : (
    <Layout>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        More code here
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

SplashScreen.jsx

```
import styles from "./splash-screen.module.css";
import Logo from "./assets/images/logo.png";

export default function SplashScreen(props) {
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <img src={Logo} alt="logo-splash" className={styles.logo} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

index.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import Home from "./routes/Home";
import Auth from "./routes/auth/Auth";
import ErrorPage from "./error-page";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
  },
  {
    path: "/auth",
    element: <Auth />,
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);
```

I only want the splash screen to activate once, when the website initially loads, and not when I'm navigating around. How can I do that?

Comment: For that you can keep a flag in the local storage i.e. opened:true and set it to true in the entry point of your app. Then you can add a check on if its not opened only then show the loading/splash.

Comment: How can I implement this? I mean, how do i save flags in local storage and how to i check/alter them?

Comment: You can refer to this documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use localStorage to store a flag whether the splash screen has been displayed or not. I'd suggest refactoring the code a bit to decouple the `SplashScreen` component from the `Home` component and routing so the splash screen can render when initially visiting the app regardless what path a user is entering the app on.

Example:

```
export default function Home(props) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        More code here
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />
  },
  {
    path: "/auth",
    element: <Auth />
  }
]);

const App = () => {
  // Initialize from localStorage
  const [showSplashscreen, setShowSplashscreen] = useState(
    () => !JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("showedSplashscreen"))
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Update local state to trigger component rerender
      setShowSplashscreen(false);
      // Update localStorage for next time app is mounted
      localStorage.setItem("showedSplashscreen", JSON.stringify(true));
    }, 4000);
  }, []);

  // Conditionally render splash screen or app router
  return showSplashscreen ? (
    <SplashScreen />
  ) : (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

[image: Edit adding-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-router-dom-reactjs-project]

*To reset, clear the sandbox's localStorage from the browser's dev tools and reload the page.*

If you would like for the splash screen to be displayed each and every time the app mounts, e.g. initial load and any page refresh/reload, then it's even more trivial: just initialize `showSplashscreen` true and don't worry about storing anything in localStorage. Each time `App` mounts, it'll display the splashscreen and then switch over to the router/routes.

```
const App = () => {
  const [showSplashscreen, setShowSplashscreen] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowSplashscreen(false);
    }, 4000);
  }, []);

  return showSplashscreen ? (
    <SplashScreen />
  ) : (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit adding-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-router-dom-reactjs-project (forked)]

Comment: Once it is set, it has to be deleted too by adding it in useEffect.

Comment: @sid Sorry, can you clarify what you mean in your comment? What are you suggesting be deleted?

Comment: when the component has been mounted, it should be set back to false in LS otherwise it would never appear again on other routes.

Comment: @sid OP only wants the splash screen to display once, when the app mounts. OP - *"I only want the splash screen to activate once, when the website initially loads, and not when I'm navigating around."* That's why I suggested moving it out of the router/routing.

Comment: @sid you're right. I closed the browser and re-opened the link again the splash screen still wouldn't display anymore :( How can I fix this?

Comment: @DavidGuri Oh, you want the splash screen to display each and every time a user mounts the app? Add a cleanup function to the `useEffect` hook that cleans up the localStorage when the app unmounts. Need me to update answer and sandbox?

Comment: @DrewReese that’d be great if you could! Sorry to bother you so much but I’m new to all of this

Comment: @DavidGuri Updated. I also realized it's much more trivial than I had initially suggested. Please check updated answer & explanation when you've time.